# How to create list dynamically based on different conditions in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, indentation

Text file:

```
Animals
  Tiger
  Lion
    Cat
      Mice
Birds
  Parrot
  Peacock
    Hen
      chicken
Reptiles
Mammals
```

I want to dynamically separate the words based on the indentation and store it in a different lists

Expected Output:

```
a=['Animals','Birds','Reptiles','Mammals']
b=['Tiger','Lion','Parrot','Peacock']
c=['Cat','Hen']
d=['Mice','Chicken']
```

Here is my code:

```
a=[]
b=[]
c=[]
d=[]
for i in text:
  indent = len(i)-len(i.lstrip())
  if indent == 0:
    a.append(i)
  if indent == 2:
    b.append(i)
  if indent == 4:
    c.append(i)
  if indent == 6:
    d.append(i)
```

It gives the expected output but I want it in dynamic approach.

Comment: maybe you should use dictionary  `data = {0:[...], 1:[...], ...}` and then you can use `data[indent].append(i)` - so it will works with any indentation and you will no need all this `if`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(list)
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        indentation_level = (len(line) - len(line.lstrip())) // 2
        data[indentation_level].append(line.strip())

for indent_level, values in data.items():
    print(indent_level, values)
```

```
0 ['Animals', 'Birds', 'Reptiles', 'Mammals']
1 ['Tiger', 'Lion', 'Parrot', 'Peacock']
2 ['Cat', 'Hen']
3 ['Mice', 'chicken']
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use dictionary

```
 data = {0:[...], 1:[...], ...}
```

and then you can use

```
data[indent].append(i)
```

so it will works with any indentation and you will no need all these `if`.

```
text = '''Animals
  Tiger
  Lion
    Cat
      Mice
Birds
  Parrot
  Peacock
    Hen
      chicken
Reptiles
Mammals'''

data = {}

for line in text.split('\n'):
    striped = line.lstrip()
    indent = len(line) - len(striped)

    # create empty list if not exists
    if indent not in data:
        data[indent] = []

    # add to list
    data[indent].append(striped)

#print(data)

for key, value in data.items():
    print(key, value)
```

Result:

```
0 ['Animals', 'Birds', 'Reptiles', 'Mammals']
2 ['Tiger', 'Lion', 'Parrot', 'Peacock']
4 ['Cat', 'Hen']
6 ['Mice', 'chicken']
```

---

In dynamic programming you should use dictionary and list instead of separated variables `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`. Eventually you could use dictinary with string keys `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"`, `"d"` but you can always convert values `0, 2, 4` to chars `a, b, c`

```
for key, value in data.items():
    char = chr(ord('a') + key//2)
    print(char, value)
```

Result

```
a ['Animals', 'Birds', 'Reptiles', 'Mammals']
b ['Tiger', 'Lion', 'Parrot', 'Peacock']
c ['Cat', 'Hen']
d ['Mice', 'chicken']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following, using a dictionary with length of indentation as keys:

```
d={}

def categ(x):
    n=0
    i=0
    while x[i]==' ':
        n+=1
        i+=1
    return n

for i in text:
    if categ(i) in d:
        d[categ(i)].append(i[categ(i):])
    else:
        d[categ(i)]=[i[categ(i):]]
```